# How to say "to grade" in Japanese? (school, university system)

Tags: words

How to say "to grade" in Japanese? (school, university system)

I saw that the words for "a grade" are 点数 *tensuu*, or 成績 *seiseki*, and that to receive a grade is said 点数を取る, but I can't find how to say 'to grade' ("The teachers graded the students assessments last night."; "The teacher forgot to grade.")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We say

成績をつける (evaluate by grades 1 to 5, A, B, C, etc. formally it is also said as 評価する)

点数をつける (give points out of 100%)

Comment: Just to check, the kanji is 付ける, right?

Comment: Yes, it is.  付ける is often written without kanji, like in  格好【かっこう】つける

Answer (score 6):

There are more than one way to say "to grade" but if I had to choose I think 採点する is the most common one in the school context.

See also https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=grade

Comment: What about in the university context?

Comment: The same works for that, too.

Comment: 分かります, ありがとうございます